# How Active Directory identifies a computer?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have no administrative rights to AD in my company. I have also a virtual machine (based on Virtual Box). I want to plug it into the AD with the same identity as my PC has.

How AD domain controller identifies a computer? I mean - what prerequisites should be met if I want the domain controller to see two machines as identical?

Comment: This will not work. Every Windows machine has an unique SID. Like S-1-5-21-211353118-160123419-83662341. Even if you would be able to clone this, it would't work, because after AD join the DC adds an other ID to the new joined Object so your SID would look like: S-1-5-21-211353118-160123419-83662341-12345. I don't think you can really jerk out AD with SID's... This is impossible...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the concept and deployment of SIDs and FSMO roles pertaining to SIDs is well documented in many Microsoft texts. It appears as though no prior research was done before asking this question.

Comment: And, also, the person asking the question is not acting in a professional IT role, if they have no administrative rights.

Comment: @DKNUCKLES, what does this have to do with FSMO roles at all?

Comment: @mfinni I'm a software developer, so maybe I'm not IT professional but I'm not, so to say, a regular user. Maybe the information is documented but definitely requires more research than few clicks, so I believe it could be helpful for many people.

Comment: @Landeeyo Given that many of the people on this site are in charge of preventing random unauthorized people from connecting random unsecured/unapproved devices to sensitive networks, we'd probably rather not "be helpful for many people" in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you join a computer to an AD domain, a domain controller assigns that computer a unique RID/SID from a pool. The computer then updates several pieces of state information with that new RID. The computer also establishes a machine account password and uploads that to the domain controller. The computer also writes to the Service Principal Names attribute of its computer object in AD. This is so it can participate in Kerberos when someone wants to use some service that the computer offers.

You could take a disk image of a computer after it has joined the domain. You would have to disable machine account password changes on the two clones, or else the two disk images would become divergent and one of them would eventually lose the ability to log on to the domain. (Machine account passwords are initiated by the domain member, not the DC.) Having both machines powered on and on the network simultaneously could also be problematic, as they will both being trying to update the same DNS record, and if you rename one of them, the other machine would no longer be able to log on. (The FQDN of the computer and the name that Active Directory has on record must match, or else the computer cannot log on to the domain.) Duplicate names on the network also has negative implications for NetBIOS. Given these limitations, I'm not sure what the practical use of this would be.